# Counter not increasing inside a for using fork()

Tags: c, process, fork

I'm working on a little project here and one of the parts requires me to do something if a flag is on and other thing is the flag is off concurrently (using `fork()`). Althought I know this could bring `mutex` problems, I cannot seem to get it working. I don't think I ever get mutex anyway.

A piece of my code looks like this:

```
int i=0;
int w;
int pos=0;
pid_t pid;
char c[1];
for(i=0;i<len;i++) //len is the length of a file I'm reading. 
{
    pid=fork();
    if(pid)
    {
        wait(&w);
    }
    else
    {
        read(fd,&c,1); //fd is an int referencing a the file i'm reading. Using open(char* [], O_RDONLY);
        printf("I'm son %d, read: %s, pos value: %d\n",getpid(),c,pos);
        if(pos==0)
        {
           printf("I'm son %d, writing out in out1.txt\n",getpid());
           //some writing instructions...
           pos=1;
        }
        else
        {
           printf("I'm son %d, writing out in out2.txt\n",getpid());
           //some writing instructions...
           pos=0;
        }
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm always getting in the same `if`, thus, I always write only in one of the files and I need to alternate the writing between two files.

```
Actual output: 
I'm son <NUMBER>, read: 0, pos value: 0
I'm son <NUMBER>, writing out in out1.txt
I'm son <NUMBER>, read: 1, pos value: 0
I'm son <NUMBER>, writing out in out1.txt
I'm son <NUMBER>, read: 0, pos value: 0
I'm son <NUMBER>, writing out in out1.txt
I'm son <NUMBER>, read: 1, pos value: 0
I'm son <NUMBER>, writing out in out1.txt
I'm son <NUMBER>, read: 0, pos value: 0
I'm son <NUMBER>, writing out in out1.txt

Desired output:
I'm son <NUMBER>, read: 0, pos value: 0
I'm son <NUMBER>, writing out in out1.txt
I'm son <NUMBER>, read: 1, pos value: 1
I'm son <NUMBER>, writing out in out2.txt
I'm son <NUMBER>, read: 0, pos value: 0
I'm son <NUMBER>, writing out in out1.txt
I'm son <NUMBER>, read: 1, pos value: 1
I'm son <NUMBER>, writing out in out2.txt
I'm son <NUMBER>, read: 0, pos value: 0
I'm son <NUMBER>, writing out in out1.txt
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your _actual_ output is nothing of the sort since it's missing, at a minimum, the output immediately after the `read`. That unfortunately makes your entire question suspect, at least in terms of possible transcription errors. Make _sure_ that your question is accurate re code, output, etc.

Comment: @paxdiablo There you go mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the effect you want, you have to control `pos` in the parent process.  Any changes made by a child are local to the child, and are lost when the child exits.

```
int i = 0;
int w;
int pos = 0;
pid_t pid;
char c[1];
for (i = 0; i < len; i++, pos = !pos)
{
    pid = fork();
    if (pid)
    {
        wait(&w);
    }
    else
    {
        read(fd, &c, 1);
        printf("I'm son %d, read: %s, pos value: %d\n", getpid(), c, pos);
        if (pos == 0)
        {
           printf("I'm son %d, writing out in out1.txt\n", getpid());
        }
        else
        {
           printf("I'm son %d, writing out in out2.txt\n", getpid());
        }
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Note that you should check for an error return from `fork()`, from `wait()` and from `read()`.  I've not coded those for you.  Also note that `!=` is not the assignment version of the `!` operator (unlike `+=` which is the assignment version of the `+` operator, for example); hence, I had to write `pos = !pos`.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, I feel kinda dumb now. Thanks for the lesson mate, I will not forget it haha! Yes, I skipped some code too, to focus on the main problem. I will check for errors now. Thanks again!

Refering to the `!=` and `=!`, thanks, I get what you're doing there. Inverse of 0 is 1 and inverse of 1 is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately after setting `pos=1`, each process calls `exit(0)` so pos can never be set to 1 in the prints.  I'm assuming it is initialized to 0 somewhere.  Keep in mind, each side of the fork is a complete and largely independent copy of the memory (a process).  So changes in one have no impact on the other(s).  This is different for threads which may be what you want.

Comment: I get this, but if I delete the `exit(0)` the process goes on forever...it won't stop `fork()` ing, where should I put it then? Should I use `sleep()` for the parent?